# JavaScript: Don't send any header

Tags: javascript, sockets, html

Using Javascript I would like to send some data to a server. Tried using `XMLHttpRequest`, but oh wonder, the data gets sent with normal HTTP headers.

Is there any way to avoid the browser sending any additional data like http headers? This would let Javascript have some socket-facility. I thought about trying to override the object XMLHttpRequest's methods. But I don't know if this is possible and how portable it is.

Maybe it doesn't really have to do anything with it... but in HTML5 this really could get useful.

Any idea to work it around? Any help appreciated.

Thanks and good night.
regards

Comment: You know about Websockets, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets Some (all?) browsers have disabled them for security reasons but they will hopefully come back.

Comment: hmm yes. already understand why they might be quite bad... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, that's no possible. You can add additional headers, but you can't disable the standard ones.

What you could do is to make a standard XmlHttpRequest request to your server, then use server side scripts to make the actual request you want.

Comment: guess that's what I'm going to do, yep. Unfortunate but it seems that there's no other way. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that or it would break a lot of things (server wouldn't like it). It has the string "Http" in it for a reason. Without headers its not HTTP. But that's why they came up the the new WebSocket interface. Maybe you could start using that.

Comment: Yep, I know that `XMLHttpRequest`. But I neither need XML nor HTTP. But as it's not possible...

Comment: You can really send any mime type using XMLHttpRequest. Another option is to send JSON instead. That's pretty common.

Comment: My idea was to send raw bytes to a remote socket, which would work if the browser didn't add any headers. And yes, I know that this is idea would result in an ugly hack.